# Password manager

Tags: password, chromium

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and chromium 86.0.4240.75. I used to be able to see my passwords in https://passwords.google.com/.
Since a while now the password manager shows the following message: "You haven’t saved any passwords in your Google Account yet."
I still have all my passwords stored and popping up when needed but I cannot see them anymore.
Can someone tell me how to get password manager to show my passwords again?
Another issue is that chromium used to offer passwords when one was requested for a website. That is not the case anymore.

Answer (score 0):

https://passwords.google.com/ will show only passwords for the currently logged Google account. For the local browser passwords try: chrome://settings/passwords

Comment: I have only one account and I am logged in.